# C++ Function pointer arguments and classes inheritance automatic cast

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, callback

First of all sorry if the name of the question is not clear enough. I really have no idea on how to call this problem.

So I have a function pointer inside a class that works like a java callback that I invoke with some parameters like itself that is derived from a parent class like in this example:

```
class Parent;

using f_Call = void(*)(Parent*);

class Parent
{
public:
    void setCallback(f_Call call)
    {
        mOnCall = call;
    }

protected:
    f_Call mOnCall = nullptr;
};

class Child1 : Parent
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        // some work..
        if (mOnCall)
            mOnCall(this);
    }
};

void onCallExe(Parent* p)
{
    Child1* child = (Child1*)p;
    // do some more work...
}

int main()
{
    Child1 child;
    child.setCallback(onCallExe);
    child.doSomething();
}
```

My question is if does c++ has a way of doing the cast from parent to children automatically in onCallExe so I don't have to do it for every function I call.

Thank you!

Comment: If you always want a `Child*` in the callback, why not change the signature accordingly?

Comment: Hi @dave the thing is that I have like 16-18 child classes in my project that will execute the function eventually.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there is an automatic way to do that. (How would the compiler know which child class to cast to for any given callback function?)
Sounds to me like you probably want more virtual functions in your `Parent` class so you don't need to cast at all.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't want to use a function pointer. You want `std::function<void()>` (yes, *without* arguments) and you want to pass a lambda with a *captured* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use function pointers. Instead, you want `std::function<void()>` (yes, *without* arguments) and pass it a lambda with a *captured* object.

```
using f_Call = std::function<void()>;

class Parent { 
public:
      void setCallback(f_Call call) {
           mOnCall = call;
      }
      protected:
          f_Call mOnCall;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
      void doSomething() {
           // some work..
           if (mOnCall)
               mOnCall(); // no argument!
       }
};

int main()  {
    Child1 child;
    child.setCallback([&child](){ /* do whatever with the child */ });
    child.doSomething();
}
```

If you want, you can hide creation of the lambda in a function template.

```
template <class Obj, class CB>
void setCallback (Obj& obj, CB cb) {
     obj.setCallback([&obj](){cb(obj);});
}
```

and then pass the global setCallback template any old function with a Child argument.

```
void onCallExe(Child1& child) { 
    // do some more work...
}

Child1 child;
setCallback(child, onCallExe);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) might be an option. However, you'll create separate base classes for each derived one, so you couldn't use them polymorphically – unless you provided a separate, common base. If the recurring template function overwrites a virtual one in the base, you might end up at where you wanted to get:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() { }
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Intermediate : Base
{
    void f() override
    {
        if(callback)
            callback(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
    void setCallback(void(*c)(T*))
    {
        callback = c;
    }

private:
    void(*callback)(T*) = nullptr;
};

struct Derived : Intermediate<Derived>
{
};

void g(Derived*) { }

void demo()
{
    Derived d;
    d.setCallback(g);
    d.f();
}
```

(If you don't need polymorphism, you can skip `Base` class – then `f` doesn't have to be virtual either.)

Solely if you wanted to set the callbacks via pointer or reference to `Base`, you are a bit in trouble, as you cannot have virtual template member functions. You could, though provide a free-standing helper function:

```
template <typename T>
void setCallback(Base& b, void(*callback)(T*))
{
    dynamic_cast<Intermediate<T>&>(b).setCallback(callback);
}
```

The dynamic cast will throw a `std::bad_cast` if `b` is of inappropriate type – unfortunately a rather costly run-time thing, a safe way to let the compiler determine if pointed/referred object is of correct type (usually) is not possible.